# Casting std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> to struct unique_ptr without losing uint8_t[] buffer

Tags: c++, casting, unique-ptr

Is there a way to cast a `std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>(n)` to `std::unique_ptr</*some_struct*/>` so that struct points to the same address as `uint8_t ptr` was as well as saving that buffer?

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(100);
std::unique_ptr<dummy> header = std::move(buffer); // error
```

```
struct dummy // string data
{
    uint64_t unk1; // 0x0

    uint64_t string_offset; // 0x8

    uint32_t c59d1c81; // 0x10

    uint16_t byte_length; // 0x14
    uint16_t string_length; // 0x16

    uint64_t unk2; // 0x18

    uint8_t* get_string() { return (uint8_t*)(uint64_t(this) + 0x8 + string_offset); }
};
```

In this example, buffer holds `0x20` bytes of `dummy` struct. However, it also contains a string which is obtainable by `string_offset` member and `get_string` method.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about _placement new_, although it's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve. I don't think there's any guarantee that your buffer has correct alignment in this case.

Comment: Pretty sure this can't be done safely the way you're trying to do it, even if alignment issues weren't a thing. `new[]` stores completely different metadata than `new`, and `std::unique_ptr` won't know that the managed memory for the `struct` has to be freed according to the rules for a plain `uint8_t` array. There are ways to create an object within it, but it would still violate the allocation rules AFAICT. Can you explain *why* you're doing this? This stinks of [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040).

Comment: Setting aside a casting issue, `unique_ptr`, by definition, means that there is no other `unique_ptr` pointer to the object. Of any type. That's what makes it a `unique_ptr`. Otherwise it wouldn't be a `unique_ptr`.

Comment: There is all manner of crazy smurf you could try with casting and `union`s, but they'll all come back to a strict aliasing violation one way or another. You can safely convert to bytes and back again, but converting a byte array to another object requires extra guarantees you'd have to manage yourself.

Comment: I'm datamining a game. After reading a block of data ( in the topic its buffer ) i have to cast it to a certain struct while keeping everything as a pointer. I have achieved my goals using raw pointers with new/new[] and just now tried to use std::unique_ptr for that.

Comment: If I was attempting this myself, I'd allocate a sufficiently-large buffer to include any necessary padding for alignment, and storage for an extra pointer following the end of the string data. That pointer would be required for correct cleanup of the buffer after. I'd use a custom deleter on the unique_ptr, along with placement new/delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring possible aliasing/alignment issues, you might do

```
auto buffer = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(100);
std::unique_ptr<dummy, Deleter> header(reinterpret_cast<dummy*>(buffer.release()));
```

With

```
struct Deleter
{
    void operator()(dummy* p) const {
        p->~dummy(); // Noop in your case
        delete[] reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(p);
    }
};
```

Comment: Great solution with unique_ptr with Deleter. But for primitive types (PODs) deleting uint* is same as deleting void*, same as deleting dummy*, isn't it? I believe it is in practise, not sure about any standard violations though.

Comment: @zzz: deleting `void*` is UB (as `void` is "incomplete" type). deleting uint* is not the same as deleting dummy* (`delete`'s type should match the `new`'s type) (even if, in practice, it would probably work).Violation is for strict aliasing and lifetime (dummy lifetime never starts currently), but unrelated to `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Brilliant custom deleter solution, Thank you! I will investigate how delete[] operator works with uint8_t* casting, but at least it works now. Btw it should have been reinterpret_cast<dummy*> in header initialize.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sorry, mistagged you. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jarod42 True. I meant  "any primitive type" instead of "void".